# A secant inequality for convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f(0) =0 $ and  $0<f''(x)<\infty (\forall$  $x>0)$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ strictly increases as $x$ increases.

I have shown that $f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{x}  = \frac{1}{2}xf''(c)$, for some $c\in (0,x)$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Did you try differentiating the function you were given? Use the mean value theorem directly. You want to interpret the condition on $f''$, not use it directly.

Comment: Let $0<a<b$, by Mean Value theorem, there exists $c,d \in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{f(b)}{b}-\frac{f(a)}{a}= (f''(d)-\frac{1}{2}f''(c))(b-a), $where $d>c$

Comment: You're working too hard. If $g(x)=f(x)/x$, use the MVT to show $g'$ is positive. Note you have to figure out how to use $f(0)=0$, as the result is false without it.

Comment: Let $0<a<b$, by Mean Value theorem and the inequality I have derived earlier, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{f(b)}{b}-\frac{f(a)}{a}= (cf''(c)-f(c))(b-a) =\frac{1}{2}f''(d)(b-a) > 0$ , for some  $0<d<c$

Comment: You're too stubborn! Please try doing what I suggested, rather than staying glued to your approach, which got you stuck. Tell me what $g'$ is and what you can conclude about it.

Comment: Please read my previous comment. I believe I have solved it:)

Comment: I have no idea how you're getting this equality with $c$ and $d$, to be honest. I don't even see where you got the equality in your original post. :( Can you post your complete argument?

Comment: Let $0<a<b$, by Mean Value theorem and the equality I have derived earlier, there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{f(b)}{b}-\frac{f(a)}{a}= (\frac{f}{x})'(c) (b-a) =(\frac{cf'(c)-f(c)}{c^2})(b-a)= \frac{1}{2}f''(d)(b-a) > 0$ , for some  $0<d<c$ ( since $f'(c) - \frac{f(c)}{c} = \frac{1}{2}cf''(d) )$.

Comment: I still can't follow at all. In particular, I can't see where your last parenthetic claim comes from. Please write the complete argument as an edit to your original post. Where do you use $f(0)=0$? BTW, you have my easier argument if you think about why $f'(x)-f(x)/x>0$ on its own.

Comment: I have used $f(0)=0$ to derive the equality relating $f'(x), f''(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis $f'' \geq 0$ means that your function is **convex**.  There are many standard inequalities involving convex functions.  This is a special case of one of them, which I call the **two secant inequality**:

> If $f$ is convex and $a < x < b$, $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{ f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

(Since your function satisfies $f'' > 0$ it is **strictly convex**, and then this and other related inequalities can be taken to be strict.)

I discuss this inequality in $\S$ 7.3.4 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).  Unfortunately the slightly later proof that $f'' \geq 0$ implies this inequality is -- as I've just noticed -- faulty.  Instead of the above inequality I derive the weaker inequality $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}$.  (In fact convex functions satisfy the **three-secant inequality** $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{ f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \leq \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}$.  Please draw a picture!)

So I feel fortunate that Ted Shifrin has sketched an alternate proof.  Let's flesh it out.  Assuming $a = f(a)  = 0$ and $f'' > 0$, we must show that the function $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.  Its derivative is

$g'(x) = \frac{xf'(x) - f(x)}{x^2}$,

so we want $h(x) = xf'(x) - f(x) > 0$ for all positive $x$; then $g' > 0$, so $g$ is strictly increasing.  Since $h(0) = 0$, it will be enough to show that $h'(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.  And indeed

$h'(x) = f'(x) + xf''(x) - f'(x) = xf''(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

I will fix the proof of Theorem 7.18 in my notes when I get the chance.  (**Added**: I incorporated into my notes the proof of Ted Shifrin in the comment below, which uses only that $f'$ is increasing.  This is with respect to my private comment.  I am also writing notes on the sequential completion of an ordered field which -- surprise, surprise -- contains some annoying details, so I haven't uploaded the corrected copy yet but I should do so relatively soon.)

Comment: Well, in fact, we don't need $f'$ to be differentiable. All we need is $f'$ increasing! $\frac{f(x)}x=f'(c)$ for some $0<c<x$, so, since $f'$ is increasing,  $\frac{f(x)}x<f'(x)$ and $g'>0$.

Comment: @Ted: thanks!  In fact in the proof I'm trying to fix I only want to assume that $f'$ is increasing, so your argument is the one that I'll use.  I'll leave this answer up for now, as it does answer the question and is somehow a little more straightforward...but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(t)=tf'(t)-f(t)-\frac{1}{2}t^2A $ defined on $[0,x]$ , where $A=2\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}$. Then, $g(0)=g(x)=0. $ By Rolle's theorem, $\exists c\in(0,x)$ such that $g'(c)=0$. It follows that $cf''(c)+f'(c)-f'(c)-cA=0$ and upon simplification, we get:  $f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}xf''(c)$

Comment: I think you have a typo in your definition of $A$. I never in a million years would have thought of this. But you now know the simpler argument I had in mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is an intuitive solution. $g=x \mapsto f(x)/x$ is the gradient of the line from the origin to $(x,f(x))$. If $g$ is not [strictly] increasing, we have a clockwise triangle $\triangle OPQ$ where $O,P,Q$ are on the curve with $P$ in the middle. But by mean value theorem on both $OP$ and $PQ$ we get $f'$ not being [strictly] increasing. Hence if $f'$ is [strictly] increasing, so is $g$.