# Proof verification - $f'(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ $\implies$ $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ under specified conditions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

**I'm stating the problem statement and my solution to it. I'd appreciate if someone checks if there's any gap in my arguments and whether the proof could be made shorter. Any other suggestions (regarding proof-writing style or other details) are also welcome. Thank you.**

> **The Problem :** Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1],$ differentiable on $(0,1)$ with $f(0)=0$. To show that if $f'$ is increasing on $(0,1),$ then $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing in $(0,1)$.

**My Solution :** Let $x,y$ be arbitrary such that $0<x<y<1$.

Since $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and is differentiable in $(0,1),$ it is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ for any $a,b$ such that $0<a<b<1,$ enabling us to apply MVT on $f|_{(a,b)}$

Applying [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on $f|_{[0,x]}$ we see that $\exists c \in (0,x)$ such that $f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)(x-0)$.

Since $f(0)=0,$ we have $\frac{f(x)}{x}=f'(c)$

Applying MVT on $f|_{[x,y]}$ we see that $\exists d \in (x,y)$ such that $f(y)-f(x)=f'(d)(y-x)$

Note that $0<c<x<d<y<1$.

Now, $\frac{f(y)}{y}-\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x)+f'(d)(y-x)}{y}-\frac{f(x)}{x}=f(x)\Big(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\Big)+f'(d)\Big(\frac{y-x}{y}\Big)$

$=f(x)\Big(\frac{x-y}{xy}\Big)+f'(d)\Big(\frac{y-x}{y}\Big)=\Big(\frac{y-x}{y}\Big)\Big(f'(d)-\frac{f(x)}{x}\Big)=\Big(\frac{y-x}{y}\Big)\Big(f'(d)-f'(c)\Big)$

Since $f'$ is increasing in $(0,1),$ and $0<c<d<1,$ we have $f'(c)<f'(d)$

Thus $\frac{f(y)}{y}>\frac{f(x)}{x}$. Since $x,y$ are arbitrarily chosen, we have $\frac{f(x)}{x}<\frac{f(y)}{y},$ for all $x,y$ such that $0<x<y<1$. Hence $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing in $(0,1)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: No remarks from me. It's just fine,

Comment: Proof looks good. See also the related [A secant inequality for convex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475267/a-secant-inequality-for-convex-functions).

Comment: Proof is correct. But don't you think taking derivatives of $g(x) =f(x) /x $ is easier? We get $xg'(x)=f'(x)-g(x)$ and by MVT we have $g(x) =f'(c) $ for some $0<c<x$. And then we can see that if $f'$ is increasing then $xg'(x)\geq 0$ so that $g(x) $ is also increasing. This is essentially same as your proof but with less amount of manipulation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! I do have the unfortunate habit of over-manipulating stuff to construct a proof. To see approaches with less amount of manipulation, like you did, is the main reason why I post these proof-verifications. I hope that I can learn from these and start coming up with nicer proofs. Thanks again!